# PPS Timer on STM32

Tags: stm32, timer, gps, time, accuracy

The MCU used is a STM32F042 which is clocked by an OCXO oscillator ([Abracon](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1883658.pdf) 10 MHz - 20 ppb). The subject of this thread is to get the best accuracy on one PPS Timer. For my application, I need to synchronize my MCU outdoors on the GPS PPS and then go indoors without any GPS Signals and keep my accurate PPS Signal.

I have a timer to get an interrupt every seconds. This interrupt has to be as close as possible to the GPS PPS. This GPS PPS is received on an interrupt pin which launch this process.

I synchronize my timer on the PPS reception but after one hour, my interrupt has drifted from 5 ms.

To get this result, here is the settings of the selected timer:

[image]

When I try the formula from ST which is:
F timer = F clock / ( 1 + Prescaler ) * (1 + Period)
with the following values : Prescaler = 199 and Period = 49999, the result is worst.

Anyone could help me? Thanks

Comment: Should it be 49750 - 1 = 49749 instead of 49999 ?

Comment: To get 1Hz the theorical values are 199 and 49999 i think.

Comment: Today to be as close as possible to 1Hz, i have to put the values 200 and 49750 which normally give me 1,0000049Hz.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.mikroe.com/blog/timer-calculator-v2-00-now-supports-stm32-and-stellaris

Comment: What Dave said - typically what you'd do here is capture the local timer count (ideally in *hardware*) on *each* PPS edge and then build a *software model* to correct any needed time reading that you would obtain from your local counter in between.  That could possibly be as simple as (last PPS time) + (local ticks since last PPS) or if you need extreme freedom from jitter some sort of software locked loop to smooth any corrections.

Comment: Clocks drift.  You can and should fix *implementation* errors in your program, but your clock is still going to drift while you are without corrective inputs.  Looking at the data sheet of your crystal, it has impressive *stability* but the *accuracy* is not inconsistent with the results you are achieving - look at the initial,  initial, reflow, and aging.  You may need to perform some sort of calibration.

Comment: With this 20 ppb oscillator, i should have 720uS of drift in ten hours. The drift is a fact, but i don't understand why my settings are the best for my project and why these settings doesn't match with the STM32 timer specifications

Comment: No, there is no promise that drift will be that low - you are misreading the promised *stability* as *accuracy*.

Comment: @ChrisStratton after reading the datasheet, how to calculate the drift expected ?

Comment: That said you should also consider doing a test of the logic, for example having both this and something else dividing down the same clock source.  Your 200 & 49750 seem to approximate what should probably be 199 & 4999

Comment: @VoltAd - worst case add all of the PPM inaccuracies specified as maximums in the same direction.   Once you get the implementation errors out of the way you could leave it logging against GPS in view of the satellites for a day and get a sense of the actual post-assembly accuracy of a particular unit.

Comment: I have written quite a lot on [using GPS as a timebase for embedded systems](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A11683+gps+1+pps). My applications had GPS available continuously, but some of this material might provide a starting point for calibrating out most of the errors in your system, leaving only the short-term stability errors. I could offer more specific suggestions if you describe your application and its actual timing requirements in greater detail.